# Building debian kernel package with custom configuration

Tags: debian, kernel, configuration

I'd like to build a jessie kernel with my configuration.

For that:

1. I download an original tarball of the kernel, debian tarball for the kernel, and "dsc" file.
2. Issue a command `dpkg-source -x ${dsc_file}`. After that I get a directory with linux sources.
3. Update changelog in linux_src/debian directory
4. Regenerate debian/rules.gen by running `debian/bin/gencontrol.py`
5. Put my config to linux_src/.config and `make olddefconfig`
6. After that I'm doing `fakeroot make -f debian/rules.gen setup_amd64_none_amd64`.

Then I check debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/.config and see there no options which were set in my config file.

What is the proper way to build the debian kernel package with my kernel configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [Section 4.5 of the Debian Kernel Handbook: "Building a custom kernel from Debian kernel source"](https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building). To quote from that section

> The easiest way to build a custom kernel (the kernel with the configuration different from the one used in the official packages) from the Debian kernel source is to use the linux-source package and the make deb-pkg target.

Let us know how you get on. I don't remember if I've tried this particular method. You can also write to the authors of the handbook directly. An alternative is kernel-package, but I haven't used that in awhile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently I'm playing with this option. But I'd like to know what other options exist for configuring.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most easier way to build a custom kernel on Debian and Ubuntu-childs.

```
sudo fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-whereveryouwanthere kernel-image kernel-headers
```